# Mapping stored procedure with conditional select

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use Entity Framework with stored procedures that have conditional selects?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lookupblogs
    (@lookup_profile VARCHAR(1)) 
AS
    IF @lookup_profile IN ( '1')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'test1' = '2', 'test2' = '2'  
    END 
    ELSE IF @lookup_profile IN ('2')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'test3' = '3', 'test4' = '4', 'test5' = '5'
    END
```

Comment: No.  You can have separate methods in your DbContext that call the same proc with different parameters and return different entities.

Comment: It's generally a really bad idea to have a stored procedure return results in **different shapes**, depending on input parameters. Any given stored procedure really should **always** return the same shape of results - and any given procedure should always be responsible only for one task (in accordance with the Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: I don't think I can convince the db developers to re develop hundreds of existing stored procedures written like that, would there be a different ORM framework that can work with these stored procedures?